# Trying to upload files with Multer to NodeJS app running on Kubernetes Pods (3 replicas)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, kubernetes, multer

I have a NodeJS app that is running on a Kubernetes cluster which has 3 pods replicas. I use Multer to upload the files to a specific folder, /public/upload with other folders in it. When I upload a profile photo, for example, it is saved on /public/upload/profiles. I want that for photos that are uploaded on one Pod, to show up on all running Pods, so for that reason I use a "Persistent Volume" and its respective "Persistent Volume Claim" connected to the /public/upload, but the uploaded photos are not showing up on all the Pods, only on the Pod that the upload was done. I leave below the whole code for Kubernetes Volume and VolumeClaim and the Multer app. I would like to have the files uploaded on one Pod to show up on all Pods, but I can't find any solution online. I thought that by creating a Persistent Volume this would be done automatically. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a configuration for this? Is it an error on configuring the Volumes?

Thank you very much for your help!

Volumes Deployment file:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testapp-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: manual
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/app-folder/uploads"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: testapp-volumeclaim
  namespace: testapp-namespace
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: manual
```

Pods and Service Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapp-deployment
  namespace: testapp-namespace
  labels:
    app: testapp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: testapp-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: testapp-container
          image: /* Repository */
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /public/uploads
              name: testapp-volume
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: testapp-secret
      volumes:
        - name: testapp-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: testapp-volumeclaim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapp-deployment
  namespace: testapp-namespace
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: testapp-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 2000
```

Multer code:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/' + req.body.folder)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.toLowerCase();
        console.log("FILE -> " + file.originalname + " ; RANDOM NUM -> " + generateRandomNumber(12) );
        cb(null, generateRandomNumber(14) + '_' + datetimestamp + '' + ext);
    }
});

var file_upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.toLowerCase();
        if(ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            return callback(new Error('Only documents are allowed'));
        }
        callback(null, true)
    },
    limits:{
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 100
    } 
});
```

Comment: `./public/uploads` is not the same as `/public/uploads` unless your app runs in the root of the container filesystem (highly unlikely)

Comment: Your comment helped me! Indeed I didn't had my app running on root. I was running on a folder /app I will create an answer to my own question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: _"I will create an answer to my own question"_... or just let it be closed as a **typo**

Comment: I think this may help others. Maybe it will became helpful to someone lost as me that couldn't find any answer online to this problem.